# vlookup error (Unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class）

Tags: excel, vba

I have an error on the vlookup, the error says 'Unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class'

this is my code:

```
Private Sub Yes_Click()

Dim input_value As Variant
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Sheet2.Range("B8:C17")

msg = InputBox("What is your name?")
If msg = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(msg, rg, 2) Then
Yes.Value = True
Else
MsgBox ("Name already in database.")
Yes.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```

There is no error if the name i keyed in is already in the database. however, there is an error when the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use that function. I’m VBA there’s a method ‘Find’ for that

```
Dim findmsg as Range
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B8:C17")
msg = InputBox(“What is your name?”)

Set findmsg = rg.find(msg)
If not findmsg is nothing then     'This condition means the names is on the database
   MsgBox(“Name already exists in database”)
   Yes.value=false
Else
   Yes.value = true
End if
```

Comment: thank you, but there is an error. VBA highlighted the word find (3rd row) and said 'method or data member not found'

Comment: I didn't add what you set as range in my code. Try adding it. Also, I don't know if you declared the sheet2 as a variable, if you didn't the correct range should be

Set rg = Sheets(Sheet2).range("B8:C17")

Comment: sorry, how do i modify the code such that it will find the exact match? because for example, the name in database is Mary. When i typed Mar, the system says that the name already exists in database.

Comment: Try adding this

findmsg = rg.find(msg, Lookat:=xlWhole)